# Laravel - Missing required parameters for [Route: appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal]

Tags: laravel

With Laravel-5.8, I tried to route from:

```
public function manager_employee_goal($id)
{
    if (! Gate::allows('appraisal_goal_review')) {
        return abort(401);
    }        

    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
    $linemanager = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('line_manager_id')->where('id', $userEmployee)->first();
    $linemanageremployee = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->pluck('id');
   $appraisedemployees = HrEmployee::select('id', 'employee_code', 'first_name', 'last_name')->where('id', $id)->get();    

    $goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $id)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->where('id', '!=', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->get();

    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal')->with('goals', $goals)->with('appraisedemployees', $appraisedemployees);        
}
```

view: manager_employee_goal.blade

```
  <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list', ['goalid'=>$goal->id]) }}">
           {{ trans('global.view') }}
  </a>
```

to this route:

```
public function manager_employee_goal_list($goalid)
{
        $goal           =       AppraisalGoal::findOrFail($goalid);
    $goaldetails    = AppraisalGoalDetail::where('appraisal_goal_id', $goalid)->get();
    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list')
                ->with('goal', $goal)
                ->with('goaldetails', $goaldetails);       
}
```

using

```
Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal/{id}', 'Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_goal')->name('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal');
Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal_list/{goalid}', 'Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_goal_list')->name('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list');
```

But I got this error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal] [URI: appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal/{id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\peopleedge\resources\views\appraisal\appraisal_goals\manager_employee_goal_list.blade.php)

How do I get it resolved?

Thank you

Comment: Please check the manager_employee_goal_list.blade.php file and not the manager_employee_goal.blade and look for the "appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal" route

Comment: Please share your manager_employee_goal_list.blade.php code

Comment: I added ? at the end of the route and it works. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Change `route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list', ['goalid'=>$goal->id])` to `url('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list', ['id'=>$goal->id])`.

Check the usage of the url generator:- https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes

Comment: The problem is still there